# callback issue for a basic arithmetic funciton

Tags: javascript, callback

If you came across these two JavaScript functions for doing the basic arithmetic operations:

```
function add(a, b, callback) 

function multiply(a, b, callback)
```

Write code using these two functions to compute the result and print out:

```
2 * (1 + 10) * 30
```

Comment: so what have you tried

Comment: What have you tried? Or are you asking us to solve this problem for you from scratch?

Comment: Well lets just say nothing I've tried has even remotely come close to being accurate.                                                                                 
 function add(a, b, callback) {
  2 *(a + b) * 30;
 callback(a,b);
}

Comment: What is the purpose of `callback` parameter?

Comment: Thum I believe it is so the rest of the function can run while waiting for the callback to run as well?